# How do I adjust this frame with scrollbar inside the black space?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to fit this frame with scrollbar(refer the provided image) in the black space present in the provided image. How do I do that. The frame should totally cover the black space.

The code for program.[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbQFe.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
C = Tk()
C.maxsize(1200, 750)
C.geometry("1200x750")
C.title("Mainscreen")
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

BG = PhotoImage(file="Mainscreen bg.png")
ML = PhotoImage(file="Music_label.png")

BG_label = Label(C, image=BG, border=0)
BG_label.place(x=0, y=0)

style.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar", gripcount=0,
                background="Cyan", darkcolor="gray6", lightcolor="LightGreen",
                troughcolor="Turquoise4", bordercolor="gray6", arrowcolor="gray6",arrowsize=15)


wrapper1= LabelFrame(C, width="1600", height="100", background="gray6",bd=0)
mycanvas = Canvas(wrapper1,background="gray6",borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=700, height=600)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand="false", padx=0)


yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical",command=mycanvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")

mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

mycanvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all")))
myframe = Frame(mycanvas)
mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="n")

wrapper1.pack(side=RIGHT,expand="false", padx=0, pady=200)

for i in range(50):
    Button(myframe, image=ML,bg="gray6",bd=0).pack()


mainloop()
```

EDIT:
[Music_Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mOXU.png)
[Mainscreen bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAjg0.png)

Comment: is wrapper1 the frame you are talking about?

Comment: if wrapper 1 is the frame, then have you tried doing expand = True?

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer yes and I have tried expand=True it is not working

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you also tell if you have tried expand = False on the Y scroll pack statement?

Comment: And is your wrapper1 within your my canvas?

Comment: One thing you can try is -: changing this `yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")` to `yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y", expand = False)`.

Comment: mycanvas is within wrapper1 and I tried expand=False it aint working. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: I am sorry I am asking you to try changing some stuff constantly but since I cannot reproduce the code without the images required to run it, So Can you try also to first pack the wrapper1 and then create the canvas window?

Comment: I have added images please refer edit section for images. Appreciate your help. Please do any renaming if any.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have tried some changes and I found out that the problem is that your myframe is not inside the mycanvas eventhough it seems like it should be.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide full code with more explanation in reply to this question, I am having hard time figuring out from comments. Thank You

Comment: I have tried posting an answer with some explanation, I hope it will be helpful, make sure to inform if you still have any problems that you might be facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying to understand the underlying problem for a while I have reached the conclusion, that the problem is with the fact that the button are being drawn in the myframe and the myframe is outside the mycanvas which contains the scrollbar. So by changing the master widget for the button from myframe to mycanvas, the problem gets fixed now the scrollbar is adjacent to the buttons. BUT, Also now the button r shifted the side since while packing the wrapper1, you did `side = RIGHT`, so I would also suggest that you use place here instead of pack, since pack depends on the space available and is not reliable if you are using a Background for your GUI and want the buttons within a portion of it.

I have changed the following lines -:

```
Button(mycanvas, image=ML,bg="gray6",bd=0).pack() # Changed to mycanvas from myframe
```

and

```
wrapper1.place(x = {YOUR X, WHERE THE BOX STARTS}, y = {YOUR Y, WHERE THE BOX STARTS}) # Use place instead..
```

You can use pack also, and change the padx and pady arguments but it will be tricky to get it to work always as expected.

The fixed code is this -:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
C = Tk()
C.maxsize(1200, 750)
C.geometry("1200x750")
C.title("Mainscreen")
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

BG = PhotoImage(file="Mainscreen bg.png")
ML = PhotoImage(file="Music_label.png")

BG_label = Label(C, image=BG, border=0)
BG_label.place(x=0, y=0)

style.configure("Vertical.TScrollbar", gripcount=0,
                background="Cyan", darkcolor="gray6", lightcolor="LightGreen",
                troughcolor="Turquoise4", bordercolor="gray6", arrowcolor="gray6",arrowsize=15)


wrapper1= LabelFrame(C, width="1600", height="100", background="gray6",bd=0)
mycanvas = Canvas(wrapper1,background="gray6",borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=700, height=600)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=False, padx=0)


yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical",command=mycanvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y", expand = False)

mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

mycanvas.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all")))
myframe = Frame(mycanvas)
mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="n")

wrapper1.pack(expand=True, padx=0, pady=200) # Use place instead

for i in range(50):
    Button(mycanvas, image=ML,bg="gray6",bd=0).pack() # Change this to mycanvas from myframe


mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked out totally fine.

Comment: No problem, Glad it could help.